# Rewriting a power series in terms of itself

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation:
$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2a_ia_{n-i}$$
Where:
$$a_0=0,a_1=1$$

I started by defining a generating function for $a_n$:
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
$$=x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2a_ia_{n-i}\right)x^n$$

I then noticed that:

$$g(x)^2=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}a_{n-i}\right)x^n$$

But I cannot seem to solve for $g(x)$ by writing it in terms of itself, due to the $\binom{n}{i}^2$ coefficient. Is there a way to do this, or would another approach be more suitable?

Comment: This is implicit since the RHS depends on $a_n$ as well, no?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: I thought so too at first, but actually it doesn't since it gets multiplied by $a_0=0$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I don't think so, since $a_0=0$ we have that $a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2a_ia_{n-i}$ is equivalent to $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}^2a_ia_{n-i}$ (the relation I am actually trying to solve)

Comment: @BenjaminCabbagepatch Thanks, my bad

Comment: Except for the $a_0$ term, this seems to be [OEIS sequence A327882](https://oeis.org/A327882) (which was added quite recently), but the entry doesn't list this recurrence relation. It does give the closed form $a_n=n(2(n-1))!$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $b_n:=\frac{a_n}{n!^2}$, so
$$\tag1b_n=\frac{a_n}{n!^2} =\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{a_i}{i!^2}\frac{a_{n-i}}{(n-i)!^2} =\sum_{i=0}^nb_ib_{n-i}.$$
So for $h(x):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i$, we formally have the simple equation $$\tag?h(x)=h(x)^2.$$
Oops - we forgot that $(1)$ does not hold for $n=1$ (where it would state $1=b_1=2b_0b_1=0$). So the correct equation needs a fix in the linear term:
$$\tag2 h(x)=h(x)^2+x.$$
Writing $h(x)=xk(x)$ (to codify the fact that $b_0=0$), we arrive at
$$\tag3 k(x)=1+xk(x)^2,$$
or 
$$k(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}.$$
Only the minus-solution converges as $x\to 0$, so
$$ h(x)=xk(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}.$$

Comment: Brilliant! I had actually tried taking out the factor of $(n!)^2$, but gave up too soon.